# How to make an extended class from an abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance

This is a inheritance problem and the thing is the Ticket class is abstract and I'm trying to make an AdvanceTicket class that extends the Ticket class. The AdvanceTicket class is supposed to act as tickets that are purchased before an event and that tickets bought 10 days before the event cost $30. Tickets purchased at least 1 but fewer than 10 days before the event cost $40.

```
public abstract class Ticket {

    private int serialNumber;

    public Ticket() {
        serialNumber = getNextSerialNumber(); { 
        }
        //returns the price for this ticket
        public abstract double getPrice();
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Number: " + serialNumber + "/nPrice: " + getPrice();
    }
    //returns a new unique serial Number
    public static int getNextSerialNumber() {
    //implementation not shown  
    }

}
```

Comment: The behavior you described should be in a controller, not in the model (Ticket). Is this homework?

Comment: I have the same type of question. I know that you would just extend Ticket but what would be inside that Advanced Ticket class?

Answer (score 2):

```
class AdvanceTicket extends Ticket
{
     public double getPrice() //you must override abstract method ie. getPrice();
     {
           .......
     }
}
```

If you **dont want to override** `getPrice()`, then declare it as **abstract** in derived class too and also declare derived class as abstract.

```
abstract class AdvanceTicket extends Ticket
{
   public abstract getPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class AdvanceTicket extends Ticket
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extend `Ticket` when creating the class.

```
class AdvanceTicket extends Ticket {
    // Implementation here
}
```

General remark about code:  If you're going to use `serialNumber`, it should be declared `static`.  Also, `/n` should be `\n`.